# Categorize group data

Tags: r

I have a dataframe of groups with diffreent levels as the following

```
g1 <- c("advanced", "advanced", "new", "moderate")
g2 <- c("advanced", "new", "new", "new")
g3 <- c("advaned", "advanced", "moderate", "moderate")
d <- data.frame(g1, g2, g3)
```

I would like to create a column with the number of categories for all columns:

```
c <- c("1", "2", "2", "2")
d <- data.frame(g1, g2, g3, c)
```

Thanks!

Comment: where is the dataframe? I only see 3 vectors. Can you show how the dataframe looks like?

Comment: I have edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
lengths(lapply(d, table))
g1 g2 g3 
 3  2  3
```

Note that g3 is giving 3 instead of what you expected 2 since you have `advaned, advanced, moderate`

Another simpler approach:

```
sapply(d, function(x)length(table(x)))
```

or even

```
sapply(d, function(x)length(unique(x)))
```

EDIT:

to do it rowwise:

```
 sapply(data.frame(t(d)), function(x) length(unique(x)))
```

Comment: The output of  this code gives the unique values across the column. I need it across the rows.

Comment: I need a column output based on rows values of all columns.

Comment: but your results expected output matches the columns and not rows: There are four rows, your result has 3 values

Comment: @amanymarey how is the first result 1? you have `advanced and advaned` those are 2 not 1